# Conditional Probability simulation with coins

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-probability

I toss a coin 3 times and the first time I have Heads and Tails for the first 2 (H1, T2). Now whats the probability to get Heads in the 3rd toss? Can you explain using Bayes theorem please? Many thanks

Comment: "The first time I have Heads and Tails for the first $2$"  makes no sense at all to me.  Have can you have two results the first time?  What does this question have to do with Bayes' rule?

Comment: You didn't specify whether the coin is fair. The answer that was provided assumes that it is; in this case the question is somewhat trivial. Perhaps you were thinking of a potentially biased coin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those events are independent. That is, getting Heads and then Tails does not affect the outcome of the third experiment. Therefore, the probability of Heads in the 3rd toss is 0.5.

In terms of Bayes theorem:

$$P(T_3=Heads|T_1=Heads,T_2=Tails)=P(T_3=Heads)=1/2.$$

Comment: This is not really Baye's theorem, but rather the definition of independent events.

Comment: Yes. I probably should have said that.